# Improving time complexity from O(log n/loglog n) to O((log ((nloglog n)/log n))/loglog ((nloglog n)/log n))

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, big-o-notation

Suppose I have an algorithm whose running time is 
 $O(f(n))$ where $f(n) = O\left(\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}\right)$

And suppose I can change this running time in $O(1)$ steps into $O\left(f\left(\frac{n}{f(n)}\right)\right)$, i.e. I can get an algorithm whose running time is $O(g(n)) = O\left(\frac{\log\frac{n}{\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}}} {\log\log\frac{n}{\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}}}\right) = O\left(\frac{\log\frac{n\log\log n}{\log n}} {\log\log\frac{n\log\log n}{\log n}}\right)$.

I'm pretty sure that $g(n) < f(n)$ for big enough $n$ (by using [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=logn%2Floglogn%20%20-%20log%28n*loglogn%2Flogn%29%2Floglog%28nloglogn%2Flogn%29%20%20between%2010and%2010000000000)) but wasn't able to prove it.

My questions are:

1. Is $g(n) < f(n)$ in fact true (starting from some n)?
2. Is $g(n)$ asymptotically better the $f(n)$, i.e. is $g(n) = o(f(n))$
3. Assuming this is asymptotically better, I can do this step again and further improve the running time of the algorithm. Meaning that in 1 more step I can make my algorithm run in time of $O\left(\frac{n}{f\left(\frac{n}{f(n)}\right)}\right)$, and I can repeat this process as many times as I want. How many times should the process be repeated to get the best asymptotically running times and what will it be? obviously repeating it $O(f(n))$ times will already have a running time of $O(f(n))$ only for the repetition of this process and will not improve the overall algorithm complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the functions. 
$$f(n) = \frac{\log(n)}{\log\log(n)}$$ 
$$h(n)=\frac n{f(n)}=\frac{n\log\log(n)}{\log(n)}$$ 
$$g(n)=f(h(n))=\frac{\log(\frac{n\log\log(n)}{\log(n)})} {\log\log(\frac{n\log\log(n)}{\log(n)})}$$

---

> 1. Is $g(n) < f(n)$ in fact true (starting from some $n$)?

Yes, here is a proof.

Let us compute the derivative of $f(x)$ with respect to $x$ as a real variable.

$$\frac{df}{dx}
=\frac{\frac{\log\log x}{x}-\frac{\log x}{x\log x}}{(\log\log x)^2}
=\frac{\log\log x-1}{x\ (\log\log x)^2}$$

So $\frac{df}{dx}\gt0$ when $e^e <x$. That means, $f(x)$ is strictly increasing once $e^e\lt x$.

If $n$ is large enough, $e^e\lt h(n) \lt n$, which implies $f(h(n)) < f(n)$, i.e., $g(n) < f(n)$.

If we want to be specific, we can show that $e^e\lt h(n) \lt n$ when $n > e^{e+2}$.

> 2. Is $g(n)$ asymptotically better the $f(n)$, i.e. is $g(n) = o(f(n))$?

No, $g(n) = \Theta(f(n))$. In fact, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}=1$

> 3. Assuming this is asymptotically better, I can do ...

Well, that assumption is invalid.

---

Here are two exercises.

**Exercise 1.** Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}=1$ using the following hint or steps.

1. Recall that $\log(n) < n^\epsilon$ for any constant $\epsilon>0$ when $n$ is large enough.
2. Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(\frac{n\log\log(n)}{\log(n)})}{\log(n)}=1$.
3. Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log\log(\frac{n\log\log(n)}{\log(n)})}{\log\log(n)}=1$.

**Exercise 2.** Show that $g(n)−f(n)=O(1)$. (This exercise might be hard.)